# Mass-Energy Equivalence and First Law of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, mass-energy

Einstein showed mass can be converted into energy and vice versa.
$E=mc^2$

However, in school we are taught that according to the First Law of Thermodynamics, energy can neither be created nor destroyed.

Are they not contradicting each other? I already tried finding it on other sites but was surprised that there was little information regarding this.

Comment: You're confusing the possibility for energy to vanish or appear (which is, indeed, impossible at least in non-quantum theories) and the possibility for energy to be converted into another form.

Comment: I'm really surprised by the close votes.  This seems like a perfectly reasonable question for someone who is new to these concepts and wants to go deeper. The cynical part of me suspects there is a tendency among some to view questions that don't have a lot of bras and kets or tensors as not worthwhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are they not contradicting each other?

Yes, there is a contradiction, but not between $E=mc^2$ and thermodynamics. The contradiction is between the actual meaning of $E=mc^2$ and its usual pop-science description. Unfortunately, although $E=mc^2$ is very famous, it is also very misunderstood. The usual English description of that equation is, as you stated, "mass can be converted into energy". However, that English description is obviously incorrect due to the conservation of energy, as you stated.

If scientists had wanted to write an equation that did state "mass can be converted into energy" then the equation would be $\Delta E = -c^2\Delta m$. This equation says that a negative change in mass gives a positive change in energy. That is what it would mean to convert between the two. So not only does $E=mc^2$ not describe a conversion, it is not intended to do so.

$E=mc^2$ is a statement at any given time. At that time a mass with no momentum has energy. There is no sense of conversion between the two. The mass and the energy are both present at the same time.

Note that I specifically said "a mass with no momentum". $E=mc^2$ only applies when $m$ has no momentum ($p=0$). In any scenario where $m$ has momentum then the more general formula is $m^2 c^2 = E^2/c^2 - p^2$.

Comment: Is it not true that $\Delta{E} = -c^2\Delta{m}$ can be a valid equation to describe the flow of energy from a non-closed system? For example, isn't that very relevant for understanding nuclear reactions? 
Also, I'm not sure why you began the answer by saying that there is a contradiction, the answer seems to explain why it isn't really a contradiction.

Comment: @Amit thanks for the feedback. You are right, I was thinking of a different contradiction than what the OP was asking about. I have revised the initial paragraph.

Comment: @Armit I'd draw a sharp distinction between the statements made about nuclear decays as opposed to energy transport across a boundary. Tracking nuclear decay energy you'd track $T = \gamma mc^2 - mc^2 = E - mc^2$, note that $E$ is a constant, and derive $T_2 - T_1 = \Delta T = E - m_1c^2  - E + m_2 c^2 = -\Delta m c^2$, while if you have energy transport across a boundary, $E$ is not a constant.

Comment: @gs - but wouldn't they be identical if you define the boundary to be the nucleus? This is really not my area, I'm just intrigued by what you wrote and trying to understand

Comment: @Armit the decay products carry away their rest mass as well as their kinetic energy, so you could express $\Delta E = \Delta \gamma mc^2$ (no minus sign), but it wouldn't be useful for predicting anything since we don't know what $\Delta \gamma m$ is unless we know both $m$ and $T$ before and after. Whereas $\Delta T = -\Delta mc^2$ tells us how much kinetic energy the decay products will have if we know $\Delta m$, or it will tell us what the mass of the decay products are if we know $\Delta T$

Comment: @gs - I think I understand, you're saying that a non closed system is necessarily characterized also by a kinetic energy flow out of the system and not only a mass induced energy flow like in your first example?

Comment: But in your "general formula" mass *is* converted to energy. In, for example, electron-positron annihilation, the mass of the particles disappears, replaced by the energy of massless photons. And it's not a more "general formula" than $E=mc^2$, it simply represents a different definition of $m$.

Comment: @Amit in an open system, we have $\Delta E = \Delta \gamma m c^2 = \Delta mc^2 + \Delta T$, no minus signs, change of total system energy equals change of total system energy. We might want to track *heat transport across the boundary*, or some other way of tracking the energy of some other **part** of a **closed** system, in which we'd have $\Delta Q = - \Delta E$, the energy leaving one part of the system is opposite the change of energy of that part of the system. [1/2]

Comment: @Amit We might want to track the change of different **kinds** of energy in a **closed** system (e.g. the system comprised of all the products of a radioactive decay, or electron-positron annihilation), in which we'd have $\Delta E = 0 \to \Delta T = -\Delta mc^2$ (grouping photon energy under kinetic energy as is conventional). In short: closed system gives us a minus sign: change of some part of the system is opposite the change in some other part of the system, whether the part is a different place or a different kind. An open system gives us no minus sign: change is change. [2/2]

Comment: @gs: I completely understand now! Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to resolve this question is to forget about more colloquial descriptions of $E=mc^2$ and just take a look at special relativity. SR imposes that the famous mass-energy relation (in natural units): $$ p_{\mu} p^{\mu} = E^2 - \vec{p}^2 = m^2$$ holds for all particles in all reference frames since $p_{\mu} p^{\mu}$ is a Lorentz invariant quantity. Furthermore, in SR we also have a conservation of total 4-momentum: $$p_{\text{initial}}^{\mu} = p_{\text{final}}^{\mu}$$ for any closed system.

In the nonrelativistic limit, the mass-energy relation reduces from $E^2 = \vec{p}^2 +m^2$ to $E = mc^2$ since the 3-momentum is small relative to the $mc^2$ term. However, the fundamental invariant quantity in SR is $p_{\mu} p^{\mu}$.

An example to think about mass and energy is found in nuclear physics. The proton and neutron can form a bound state called the deuteron with a mass $m_d = m_p + m_n - 2.2 MeV$. Thus, to break apart the deuteron, you need to put in at least 2.2 MeV of energy and you'll get out two particles with "greater mass than you started with" (seemingly $m_d \rightarrow m_p + m_n $, which apparently violates mass conservation). But to correctly understand what happened you must take both the energy and mass into account and you'll see conservation: $m_d + 2.2 MeV \rightarrow m_p + m_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Mass is not converted to energy.  Mass *is* energy.  Sometimes mass energy can be converted into heat energy or light energy, or vise versa (as in chemical or nuclear reactions).  Thermodynamics always applies regardless to these transfers or conversion of energy.  In most thermodynamics and chemistry contexts, the amount of heat or mechanical (pressure) or chemical energy released or absorbed is incredibly small compared to the mass energy of the reactants and products - so when making computations, it is typically assumed that mass is constant, and only the other forms of energy are accounted for.

For example, in a reaction of 1 kg of hydrogen and oxygen gas:

$$ H_2+\frac 1 2 O_2 \rightarrow H_2O$$

the resulting water vapor product weighs about 0.1 micro grams ($1\times 10^{-10}$ th of a kg) less than the original mixture.  This minute difference accounts for the mass energy released as heat and light energy.  But in the context of chemistry, this is usually accounted for by saying the mass is constant (which is nearly true, and certainly to the limits of our measurements), while the heat and light energy came from the change in "chemical potential energy" associated with the reaction.

Bottom line is: $E=mc^2$ and thermodynamics are both always true, but the former is typically not relevant in chemistry or most everyday thermodynamic problems.